# Should I loop for every button using jquery to get the id?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pug, bootstrap-modal

This is a snippet of my jade file:

```
ul#posts(data-role="listview")
        - each post in posts
          li(id=post._id, class="list-group-item list-group-item-success")
            a(id="btn") 
              p #{post.post.title} &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp  #{post.post.date}
```

So, this shows a list of posts fetched from my database.
Now using jquery in a diff js file, this is what I have:

```
$(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}); 
$('#btn-save').click(function(e){
    window.location.href = "/subscribe/#{post._id}";
});
});
```

I am using bootstrap to create the pop up page making the user verify his click.

The problem is that the `.click` function only works for the first post of my whole list
and what I want is that it functions every time a user clicks on any of the posts.

Comment: can't repeat id's in a page, they are unique by definition, use class instead for your `btn` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `class` selector instead of an `id` selector as all `id`s must be unique. Once you modify your buttons to have the `.btn` and  `.btn-save' classes, you can use the following:

```
$(function(){
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}); 
$('.btn-save').click(function(e){
    window.location.href = "/subscribe/#{post._id}";
});
});
```

Obviously not tested but this should work just fine! You may need to modify the code to use jQuery's `each` if this doesn't work.

Edit: I see the question was already answered in the comments. Awesome :)